# Get id from single column array laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have DB like this

```
|id|      email     |departement_id|
|1 |test1@gmail.com |1,2           |
|2 |test2@gmail.com |3,4           |
|3 |test3@gmail.com |5,1           |
|4 |test4@gmail.com |2,6           |
```

I trying to get `id` data for send email, from `departement_id`. If from request POST `departement_id` is 2, so the `id` must 1 and 4. How can I get the id in Laravel? because the data in single column-`departement_id`-is array.

this is my send email function...

```
Mail::send('mails.thanks',['ticket'=>$request, 'department' => $department], function ($message) use ($departement){
                $message->from(Config::get('const.email'), 'Ticket Plus');
                $message->subject('Nueva tarea creada');

                // get id user and send email user
                $getUsers = User::where('department_id',  [(int)$departement])->pluck('id')->toArray();
                $role_users = DB::table('role_user')
                             ->whereIn('user_id', $getUsers)
                             ->where('role_id', 2)
                             ->pluck('user_id')
                             ->toArray();
                $getMailUsers = DB::table('users')
                             ->whereIn('id', $role_users)
                             ->pluck('email')
                             ->toArray();

                foreach ($getMailUsers as $getMailUser)
                {
                    $message->to($getMailUser);
                };
                // $message->to($settings->admin_email);
            });
```

Thanks a lot..

Comment: You need to normalise your database. You are not allowed to have an "array" as a value in a relational database.

Comment: yes agreed. normalise your database. don't put the departments_id in 1 column like that. It's better to have a extra lookup table wich holds the user_id and department_id. Then the query becomes much easier

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Users = User::whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET('.(int)$departement.', department_id) > 0')
```